# To get the first word before the first delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I need to update a column to get only the word before the first dot. 
Code has nvarchar as data type.

Example - Table_A

```
Id   Code
1    TXT.yut.get
2    yep.no
3    gT.YU.iop
4    gip
```

I need to get this after the update

```
Id   Code
1    txt
2    yep
3    gt
4    gip
```

I have tried with T-SQL:

```
Update table_A
SET Code=lower(SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX('.',Code) - 1))
```

I get this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

It seems it can be related with 'invisible' spaces? How to overcome it? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you also have values in your table where there are no delimiters (or it's the first character?). What would you expect for the values `'.hi'` and `'png'`?

Comment: yes, there are some cases where there are no delimiters. I added one example above.

Comment: png -> png .   The kind of value as .hi will never happen... but if so:

hi would be the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All above answers will get the job done, I'll also include two different approaches as well :

**With CASE**

```
UPDATE Table_A
SET 
    Code = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Code) > 0 THEN LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX('.', Code) - 1) ELSE Code END
```

and also this **Without CASE**:

```
UPDATE Table_A
SET 
    Code = LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX('.', Code) - 1) 
WHERE 
    CHARINDEX('.', Code) > 0
```

The only different here that will only grab the first dot from each row. Unlike the `LIKE %.%` which will cover all dots on each row. If there is not a dot, the result of `CHARINDEX('.', Code)` will be zero.

Answer (score 3):

Include `WHERE` clause :

```
UPDATE table_A
     SET Code = LOWER(SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX('.',Code) - 1))
WHERE Code like '%.%';
```

Comment: Or maybe `LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX('.', Code) - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Update table_A
SET Code=substr(Code,1,instr(Code,'.',1)-1)
where Code like '%.%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT(Code, LOCATE(".", Code)-1) AS left FROM table_A
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.